# Recognize forwarding when checking if url exists

Tags: r, rcurl, httr, xml2

I have some URLs I need to crawl. I do not know how many there are. That is why I just iterate through them.

Unfortunately when a page does not exists `xml2::read.html` gets an error that breaks my loop. When I use `Rcurl::url.exists` or `httr::http_error` to check if HTML exists I get no indication the pages aren't there because I get forwarded.

```
> url <- "https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/h-tk-20152016-1-6"
> xml2::read_html(url)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
> url.exists(url)
[1] TRUE
> httr::http_error(url)
[1] FALSE
```

The URL should produce an error (which it does for xml2) but both RCurl and httr get no indication the site isn't there.

I use the following options for RCurl

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = FALSE,
                            followlocation = FALSE,
                            autoreferer = FALSE,
                            nosignal = TRUE))
```

Any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because this server returns `200 OK` when you send a HEAD request (like `url.exists()` and `http_error()` do). When send a GET request you receive the `404 NOT FOUND`.

So you can do

```
httr::http_error(httr::GET(url))
#> TRUE
```

Even better, you can save the result of the GET request and process it's `content`. This way you only need one request in any case. If there is an error you skip it, otherwise you process the result (e.g. with `xml2` or whatever you use)